# Unreal Engine 5 C++ - initializing class doesnt work

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

Hey I'm currently trying to debug my game but whenever I try i get the following errors:
"syntax error: missing ';' before '*'" -> line 30 of my code and
"missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int" -> line 30 aswell
"unexpected token(s) preceding ';'" -> also on line 30

My code looks like this:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "GameFramework/SaveGame.h"
#include "MyDataConfig.h"
#include "AbilityConfig.h"
#include "QuestsConfig.h"
#include "PlayerHUDCpp.generated.h"


UCLASS()
class WOWFAKECPP_API UPlayerHUDCpp : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()



public:

    bool target = false;
    int DisplayedQuest = 0;
    bool QuestOpen = false;
    //FString accept = "Accept";

    UQuestsConfig* MyQuestConfig;
    UMyDataConfig* MyDataConfig;
    UAbilityConfig* MyAbilityConfig;
```

The last line is line 30. As you can see the classes above "UAbilityConfig* MyAbilityConfig;" work but the last doesnt...

I tried cleaning the project, deleted the "saved" and "intermediate" folder and restartet my pc multiple times but none of them seem to work because as soon as I try debugging the project I get the errors I showed above
I don't know what I should do anymore, please help me.

Comment: Does AbilityConfig.h include the file shown?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't 'cause then it would be a simple circular dependency 
it could be the compiler but the 2 above work so I myself + ChatGPT couldn't find the problem

Comment: Aren't you just missing closing `}` on last line?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your "all code" for that file, then you are clearly missing ending bracket `}`.

It should look like this:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "GameFramework/SaveGame.h"
#include "MyDataConfig.h"
#include "AbilityConfig.h"
#include "QuestsConfig.h"
#include "PlayerHUDCpp.generated.h"


UCLASS()
class WOWFAKECPP_API UPlayerHUDCpp : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()



public:

    bool target = false;
    int DisplayedQuest = 0;
    bool QuestOpen = false;
    //FString accept = "Accept";

    UQuestsConfig* MyQuestConfig;
    UMyDataConfig* MyDataConfig;
    UAbilityConfig* MyAbilityConfig;
}
```